# Can't deploy React Js Pj on GitHub with gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404:

[image]

I will use **gh-page** lib to deploy my react js project from GitHub but `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` that is not working